# How to get some character from a string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string

```
string str = "2952885619_Table!$1$4";
```

and I would like to extract the value 1 and 4.

I have tried with

```
int index =str.IndexOf('$');
if (index > 0)
{
    int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(string.Substring(index, index + 1));
    int colIndex = Convert.ToInt32(BookmrkID.Substring(index, index + 3));
}
```

but it throws a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` and I don't know why.

Are there other ways to extract these two values?

Answer (score 2):

You can get your string starting from `$` with `string.Substring` and `string.IndexOf`, then you can split your string on `$` and remove empty entries. That will give you `1` and `4` as string values, Later you can parse them to `int` like:

```
List<int> list = str.Substring(str.IndexOf('$'))
                        .Split(new[] { '$' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Select(int.Parse)
                        .ToList();
```

Your `list` would contain `1` and `4` as integer values.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way you could do it:

```
var splits = str.Split('$');
var rowIndex = splits[1];
var colIndex = splits[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of the string.Substring call is a length not an ending range. You would have to calculate the difference of where an item lies in the string:

```
 if (index > 0){
  int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(string.Substring(index, 1));
  int colIndex = Convert.ToInt32(BookmrkID.Substring(index + 2, 1));
}
```

Doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As long as you *know* that there will only be one digit, you need to set the length of the substring (the second parameter) to 1:

```
int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(str.Substring(index + 1, 1));
int colIndex = Convert.ToInt32(str.Substring(index + 3, 1));
```

If you don't know the number of digits, you'd have to do a little more work:

```
int index1 = str.IndexOf('$');
if (index1 > 0) {
    int index2 = str.IndexOf('$', index1 + 1);
    if (index2 > 0) {
        int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(str.Substring(index1 + 1, index2 - index1 - 1));
        int colIndex = Convert.ToInt32(str.Substring(index2 + 1, str.Length - index2 - 1));
    }
}
```

Of course, the strategies that others have posted will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

here you named your variable

```
string str = "2952885619_Table!$1$4";
```

and here you call function substring on variable string and bookmrkID

```
Convert.ToInt32(string.Substring(index, index + 1));
```

try

int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(str.Substring(index, 1));

Answer (score 0):

The [overload of `string.Substring` that takes two arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) describes its second parameter as follows:

> length
>
> Type: System.Int32
>
> The number of characters in the substring.

You are passing `index + 1` and `index + 3` for the second parameter, respectively, while that should probably be something like `1` both times (seeing that both `1` and `4` have a *length* of 1 character).

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** You can use `String.Split()` function to split your string based on `$` delimeter.

**Step 2:** you just ignore the first part of splitted string.

Try This:

```
string str = "2952885619_Table!$1$4";
var items = str.Split('$');
var item1 = Convert.ToInt32(items[1]);
var item2 = Convert.ToInt32(items[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go for the first and last `$` and read just 1 character on (if the numbers are always one character in length)

```
string str = "2952885619_Table!$1$4";
var first = str.IndexOf("$");
var last = str.LastIndexOf("$");
Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(first+1,1));
Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(last+1,1));
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/LOIXZ71902

or, if they're variable length it becomes very slightly more complex:

```
string str = "2952885619_Table!$1234$4321";
var first = str.IndexOf("$");
var last = str.LastIndexOf("$");
Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(first+1,last-(first+1)));
Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(last+1));
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/VFDOP75481

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var list = str.Split('$');
int rowIndex = int.Parse(list[1]);
int columnIndex = int.Parse(list[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one-liner which is safe even if the string doesn't contain `$`:

```
string[] values = str.Substring(str.IndexOf('$') + 1).Split('$');
```

The fastest way to convert them to an `int[]` (without validation):

```
int[] intValues = Array.ConvertAll(values, int.Parse);
```

with validation:

```
int i;
int[] intValues = values
    .Where(v => int.TryParse(v, out i))
    .Select(v => i)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to match a *pattern* (which it seems you are) you can easily solve this by using RegEx.

The unit test below (NUunit) finds the pattern dollar-sign+digit(s)+dollar-sign+digit(s). You get a result of all matches, and by enclosing the digit-parts **\d+** in parenthes you can access them in the collections provided in the resulting parameter "matches".

For more on RegEx: [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Hope this helps!

```
    [Test]
    public void Find_index_in_string()
    {
        // Arrange
        const string str = "2952885619_Table!$1$4";

        // Act
        var matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"\$(\d+)\$(\d+)");

        // Assert
        Assert.That(matches.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
        Assert.That(matches[0].Groups[0].ToString(), Is.EqualTo("$1$4"));
        Assert.That(matches[0].Groups[1].ToString(), Is.EqualTo("1")); // Extracted index 1
        Assert.That(matches[0].Groups[2].ToString(), Is.EqualTo("4")); // Extracted index 2
    }
```